# Python ImportError: No module named datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, module, importerror

I'm getting an error while trying a simple datetime import.

**ImportError: No module named datetime**

I'm trying the following code in the git console.

```
>>> from datetime.datetime import strptime
```

I have tried re-installing python and it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`datetime.datetime` is a class `datetime` inside a module `datetime`.  You can't import a method of a class, which is effectively what you are trying to do. Instead, you can:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(...)
```

or to "extract" the method the way you seem to want it:

```
strptime = datetime.strptime
```

though the name on the left side of the `=` is completely up to you.

The error message itself is coming from the second `datetime` in `datetime.datetime`, not the first.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datetime.datetime'; 'datetime' is not a package

Because I imported [now](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) as shown below:

```py
from datetime.datetime import now

print(now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

So instead, I imported [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")) # 07:24:47
```